# Trying to make an img src change on click with javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, click

I want to have a menu button (with the text "menu"), and flip it around using rotateX, then have it turn into the text "close" afterwards. Originally I was trying to do it with text and animation, then text and  transform, and when that didn't work I decided I'd make an .svg of the "close" text already flipped so I only had to do 180 degrees.

My main issue is that either the item flips and transforms and doesn't transform as it flips back, or it does it once and then doesn't work again afterwards.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-items");

  
  menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("open");
    if (menu.src === './icons/menu.svg') {
      menu.src = './icons/close.svg';
      menu.classList.toggle('menu-flip');
    } else {
      menu.classList.toggle("menu-flip");
      menu.src = './icons/menu.svg';
    }
  })
};

navSlide();
```

```css
#menu {
  font-family: "Syne Regular", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 54px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 42px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
  &.menu-flip{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <img id="menu" src="./icons/menu.svg" alt="menu" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is my answer on a different post - with a similar problem)

If you want a button which replaces the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element, with a different image each time, then you can view my JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/f0a2s6pg/

Otherwise, here is a code snippet:

```js
var imgJson = {"items":[{
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/200\/300'
}, {
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/201\/301'
},
{
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/202\/302'
},
{
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/203\/303'
}
]}

var amount = 0
document.getElementById('imageBtn').onclick = function () {
    console.log("Replacing image...");
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", imgJson.items[amount].img);
    console.log(amount);
    if (amount == 3) {
        amount = 0;
    } else {
        amount++;
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/203/303" style="display: block;">
<button id="imageBtn" style="margin-top: 10px;">Random image</button>
```

Comment: Aaaaah thank you so much a counter is exactly what I needed... It's running perfect. Really appreciate you taking time to answer :)

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help.